# Samsung Galaxy y does not boot even after factory-reset

Tags: factory-reset, boot, samsung-galaxy-y

Suddenly my *Samsung Galaxy Y* start to stuck at Samsung screen (not the initial Galaxy Y screen) and keep on restarting after that point. [The situation is verymuch similar to this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4ta5puJhIs).

I did a factory-reset from recovery mode when I have sdcard in it and found no luck
then I re did the factory-reset after removing sdcard and still no luck

What are other options I have to recover from this point?

Comment: Are you sure you mean [hard-reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/hard-reset/info) – and not [factory-reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info)? Also: Any idea what might have led to the situation – any changes you've applied to the device? Is it rooted, and did you perform any actions involving root before the issue started?

Comment: No idea why.Hard reset, not factory reset. Did not root.

Comment: So you really just took the battery out (hard-reset) while in recovery mode? I think you confuse the terms here (which is why I linked them; please follow the links in my previous comment). Hard Reset is just cutting power (like with the "reset" button on your computer). Factory reset is what you do from recovery to reset the device to factory settings, deleting all user-apps and user-data. So again, are you sure you just did a hard reset? Then I recommend booting to [safe-mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/safe-mode/info) and see if that works.

Comment: Sorry if I confused. This is what I mean by hard reset (First method in this link) http://www.hardreset.info/devices/samsung/samsung-s6310-galaxy-young/

Comment: Quoting from there: *Then select from Recovery Mode menu "wipe data / **factory reset"*** Yeah, the terms are often confused. OK, but in this case I'm afraid choices are only few: if the device is still under warranty, I'd contact Samsung support, so their techs should take care for it (send it for repair). If not, there might be something [odin](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/odin/info) can do for you – but that's then better explained by someone familiar with that tool.